# How to find region of convergence of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the region of convergence of the following series$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\frac{n^2}{4}}\cdot(x-1)^{\frac{n}{3}}$$

I have done: $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\left(-\frac{n}{4}\right)}\sim{e^{-\frac{n}{4}}}$$But what is the next step to find region of convergence?

Comment: @MarkViola No, just look at the updated series, please)

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Consider the limit of
$$L:=\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-\frac{n}{4}}|x-1|^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{|x-1|^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^{1/4}}.$$
What happens when $L<1$ or $L>1$? What about the case when $L=1$?

P.S. Remember that when $L=1$ a more detailed analysis is needed since the root-test is inconclusive. We have that $|x-1|^{\frac{1}{3}}=e^{1/4}$ and 
$$|a_n|=e^{n/4}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-\frac{n^2}{4}}=\left(\frac{e^n}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}\right)^{1/4}\to e^{1/8}\not=0$$
where in the last step a Taylor expansion (or Hopital) is needed. Hence the series is not convergent when $L=1$.

Comment: Is that Cauchy root test?

Comment: Yes, that is the root-test.

Comment: Thank You, I really got it!!! L cannot be greater or equals 1, because the series will be divergent. Thank You!!!

Comment: @user449529 In the case $L=1$ it is inconclusive. The series may diverge, converge conditionally, or converge absolutely. You always need to check the endpoints when applying root/ratio test, etc. when finding intervals of convergences.

Comment: @Dragonite If I follow You, here will be enough to solve inequality L < 1?

Comment: Should there be $e^{\frac{1}{4}}$ in the denominator instead of $e^4$?

Comment: @MikkoPesonen Yes, you are right

Comment: Find out what value of $x$ makes $L = 1$, and then plug that back into the initial series and find out if it converges or diverges using series techniques.

Comment: @Dragonite Thank You very much